# find element in webbrowser and add to list box Respectively in csharp

Tags: c#, selenium, dom

I have a large number of web pages and each of these pages is the specifications of the drug. I want to display all the drug information from the first to the last, which contains 13 fields in the box list, respectively. It does not find the class value when I use the following code

```html
<div class="row">
    <span class="titleSearch">
        <img src="/content/Images/pointSearchDetail.jpg" /> info
    </span>
</div>



<div class="borderSearchDetail"><span class="borderMinSearch" /></div>
<br />
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">name :</label>
            <span class="txtAlignLTR">
                METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE

            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">public name :</label>
            <bdo class="txtAlignLTR">
                METHYLPREDNISOLONE ACETATE INJECTION, SUSPENSION PARENTERAL 40 mg/1mL 
            </bdo>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">oxr :</label>
            <span class="txtAlignLTR">
                INJECTION, SUSPENSION
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack"> masraf :</label>
            <bdo class="txtAlignLTR">
                PARENTERAL
            </bdo>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">company:</label>
            <span class="txtSearch1">
                alborz
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">brand company :</label>
            <span class="txtAlignLTR">
alborz                                        <img src="/content/Images/CountriesFlag/IR.gif" style="visibility: visible" title="iran" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">Creator :</label>
            <span class="txtAlignLTR">
                alborz
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">date :</label>
            <span class="txtAlignLTRFa">
                1397/12/24
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">cost  :</label>
                <span class="txtAlignLTRFa priceTxt">
                    49500
                </span>
            <span class="txtAlignLTR">
                ریال
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">cost 2 :</label>
                <span class="txtAlignLTRFa priceTxt">
                    49500
                </span>
            <span class="txtAlignLTR">
                $
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearchEnglish-ltr colorBlack">:GTIN </label>
            <span class="txtAlignLTRFa">
                06260152433031
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearchEnglish-ltr colorBlack">:IRC </label>
            <span class="txtAlignLTRFa">
                3230858996456396
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            <label class="txtSearch colorBlack">count: </label>
            <bdo class="txtAlignLTR">
                1 AMPULE in 1 CARTON
            </bdo>
        </div>
```

I'm looking to get variables and write them in the list box .
and i use the code C#

```
HtmlElementCollection doc1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("class");
            foreach (HtmlElement i in doc1)
            {
                try
                {
    
                    listBox1.Items.Add(i.InnerText);
                    button1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
                }
                catch { }
            }
```

but not fond Class :(. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<class>` in "*your*" page; and you are searching exactly a tag with the name class, that's why you cannot find anything.

If you are using selenium i suggest you to use the `WebDriver`.
Even if I think you don't need this locator, to extract every tag with a class you can do something like:

```cs
foreach(WebElement we in webdriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*[class]")))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(we.InnerText);
    button1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
}
```

Probably you will need to find the best parent element and then, for each, search the nested values you want.

To understand which selector to use i suggest you this [very nice cheat sheet](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/imported/1269-Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf?file=4937).